# Obtaining values from Google Maps Directions API returned JSON

Tags: python, json, google-maps

I am trying to retrieve specific values from the JSON returned via the Google Maps Directions API for python. So far what I have below will get me the [JSON data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhsk5yerhv9eedc/response.json?dl=0) and print it to the screen, but I'm having trouble getting the specific value of "distance" (111 mi) from the first "leg" attribute.

```
 now = datetime.now()
 directions_result = gmaps.directions("Sunnyvale, CA", "Elk Grove, CA", mode="driving", departure_time=now)
 json_data = json.dumps(directions_result, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
 pprint.pprint(json_data)
```

I was wondering what the best possible method would be to extract this data for use within the rest of my program. Trying

```
 print(json_data['legs'])
```

only induces

```
 TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

and I'm not quite sure as to which method when dealing with JSON. Any help?

Comment: Please specify the returned JSON string.

Comment: @Karthi I linked it in the description. It's pretty long so I didn't want to paste it and make the post even longer.

Comment: The JSON string you provided is not a valid Json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was in issue with how I thought the API worked vs. how it really works. I took a look at the API code directly and realized the JSON that is being returned is already formatted and does not need to be loaded or dumped as I thought. I was essentially adding another layer that did not need to be there. Instead I was able to manipulate directions_result directly without the need for any additional JSON modules.